# Is there a way to enforce typesafety for Angular providers with dependency injection?

Tags: angular, angular-providers, angular-dependency-injection

I would like to use dependency injection to swap the implementation of the provider but can't figure out how to make that type safe.

```
@Injectable()
class ExampleService {
    exampleMethod(): string {
        return 'test';
    }
}


// Note that this service does not implement the `exampleMethod` that the component will need.
@Injectable()
class SomeOtherService {
    someOtherMethod(): number {
        return 0;
    }
}


// Using Angular dependency injection this causes runtime errors because type safety
// is lost. Any injectable class can be injected via `useClass` even if the services are
// completely different.
@Component({
    providers: [
        { provide: ExampleService, useClass: SomeOtherService }
    ]
})
export class ExampleComponent {

    constructor(private service: ExampleService) {
        service.exampleMethod();
    }

}
```

I could create an abstract class that both services implement but there is no way to enforce that, as in someone else could create a service and inject it without using that abstract service.

Is there a way to trigger compile-time errors using Angular dependency injection? I would like to prevent the runtime errors that happen in the above example.

Potential workaround that addresses my concern: https://github.com/tygern/safe-provide

Comment: Use an injection token and an interface.